# How can I display second level children only from a specific parent structure item?

Tags: craft3, structure, navigation, children, parents

I'm trying to display a list of child structure links, but only from a specific parent. The template I'm working on isn't for the parent in question so I don't think I can use 'entry.'

My structure is set up like this

- **Parent 1**
- --Child One
- --Child Two
- --Child Three
- **Parent 2**
- --Child One
- --Child Two

I only want to display the children of Parent 1. What I have so far is

```
<ul id="sub-menu">
{% set pages = craft.entries.section('visit').level('>1') %}
{% nav entry in pages %}
<li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
           {% children %}
        </ul>
     {% endifchildren %}
</li>
{% endnav %}
</ul>
```

Using this outputs all of the second level children instead of just the children from Parent 1. Is there any way to specify that the only children I want to display must come from Parent 1? Can I specify a slug somehow?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes you can!

You may search for a slug `craft.entries.slug('slug-of-first-parent')`, select the first result `.one()`, and then the children by `.getChildren()`. Now you can proceed as you already did and limit your result to only elements with a level greater than 1 `.level('>1')` and list.

```
{% set pages = craft.entries.slug('slug-of-first-parent').one().getChildren().level('>1') %}
```

I am not sure whether this is the best and most effective solution, but it should definitely do the job.

**Tip:** You can display information about an entry and the methods and variables available by dumping them either by using `var_dump($variable)` in php code or `{{ d($variable) }}` (by using [this](https://github.com/studioespresso/craft3-dumper) free plugin) in your twig template. This can help a lot when dealing with entries and finding children or parents.